# ElementNotInteractableException - trying to click on a element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm facing an error trying to click on an element as follows:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.80)`
```

Code trials:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='idSIButton9']").click()
```

Html:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the url, is it public facing?

Comment: URL is not public

Comment: Let me share the URL : https://vollee-dev.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: for the url :  vollee-dev.azurewebsites.net , I am trying write python automation script to login. for this line of code (SignIn) : driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='idSIButton9']").click()  I get the above error.

Comment: Ok, I see a login page there, 2 buttons - login & signup, and another alt-logins with Google/Ms. What are you trying to achieve there? Login? Signup? I see no element with `id = idSIButton9`.

Comment: I am trying to login with alt-logins with Ms. After entering email and password I want to click on signin for which the xpath is id="idSIButton9" then i get the error

Answer (score -1):

As per the HTML:

[image: button]

The element is a `<button>` tag not an `<input>` tag. So `(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='idSIButton9']")` may not work.

---

### Solution

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button.bits[type='button']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='button bits' and text()='Buy Now']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```